# How to distribute iOS app with Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like someone to help me out in order to distribute my ios app successfully.
I made a simple ios app with firebase push notification service as following steps.

## 1. Added IOS certificate with Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox) in Development

## 2. Upload Development APNs certificate to firebase cloud messaging as below picture.

[image]

## 3. Everything is fine. I could send notification successfully in my iPhone without any problem.

My question is from here. I want to distribute my app to app store and I would like to check my distribution steps are going to be right or wrong. please take a look my questions and the following steps then give me advice.

Q1 : For distribution my app, What production certificate do I have add between **App Store and Ad Hoc** or **Apple Push Notification service SSL** (Sandbox & Production) ?

Q2 : If I need to add **Apple Push Notification service SSL** (Sandbox & Production), Do I need to upload the production certificate to **No production APNs certificate** area of the above image ?

Q3 : Do I need to download **GoogleService-Info.plist** again ? if so, do I have to replace the current GoogleService-Info.plist of xCode ?

I really wish someone who knows or experienced this case to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1: you can use any of the two certificates to use it as production certificate: **App Store and Ad Hoc** or **Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)**

For Q2: Yes, exactly. You need to upload that certificate to **No production APNs certificate** area of the above image.

For Q3: you do not require to download .plist file again.

Wow! you're done. Good to go, my friend.